# In linux bourne shell: How to count the occurrences of a specific word in a file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

By *word*, I mean any whitespace-delimited string.

Suppose the file `test.txt` has the following words delimited by spaces:

```
hello hello hello hell osd
hello
hello 
hello
hellojames beroo helloooohellool axnber hello
way
how
```

I want to count the number of times the word *hello* appears in each line.

I used the command `awk -F "hello" '{print NF-1}' test.txt` to show the number of occurrences of the word *hello* in each line:

```
3
1
1
1
4
0
0
```

So it find a total of 3+1+1+1+4 = 10 occurrences.

The problem is the on fourth line: *hello* only occurs 1 time as a separate word; words such as *hellojames* and *helloooohellool* should not be counted because *hello* is not delimited by whitespace.

So I want it to find 7 occurrences of *hello* as a separate word.

Can you help me write a command that returns the correct total of 7 times?

Comment: Do you need the number of occurrences in each line, or just the total?

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="hello") c++ } END{ print c }' file.txt
```

If you need it to print every line:

```
awk '{ c=1; for(i=0; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="hello") c++; print c }'
```

Comment: Actually, the third line, After this "hello", there is a hidden white space behind this hello,
so when I counted that, hello[space] nextline, which means this is a hello[space] rather than just one
"hello" word

it works, thanks

Comment: Sorry, off-by-one; the fields go 1-NF. Not sure why your third line is off, perhaps you have a funny non-printing character in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -o '\<hello\>' filename | wc -l
```

The `\<` and `\>` bits are word boundary patterns, so the expression won't find `foohello` or `hellobar`.

You can also use `awk -F '\\<hello\\>' ...` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' test.txt | grep -w hello  | wc -l
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' text.txt
```

This replaces every span of whitespace with a newline, effectively reformatting the file `test.txt` so it has one word per line.  The command `sed 's/FIND/REPLACE/g'` replaces the `FIND` pattern with `REPLACE` everywhere it appears.  The pattern `\s\+` means "one or more whitespace characters", and `\n` is a newline.

```
grep -w hello
```

This extracts only those lines that contain `hello` as a complete word.

```
wc -l
```

This counts the number of lines.

---

If you want to count the number of occurrences per line, you can use the same technique, but process one line at a time:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' | grep -w hello  | wc -l
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in `cat test.txt`; do
  if [[ ${word} == hello ]]; then
    helloCount=$(( ${helloCount} + 1));
  fi;
done;

echo ${helloCount}
```

Comment: UUoC!  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html  (Also UUo${} but I haven't found a web site for that yet.) :-)

Comment: That won't work.  He wants a count *per line*.  This replicates the behavior of `grep -c` (i.e. it counts per *file*).

Comment: @AdamLiss This isn't a UUoC.  Cat is needed for the for-loop to work properly.  He is essentially wanting to read the file to stout, which your link explicitly states is a valid use of cat.

Comment: @AdamLiss Awww snap!  I forgot about that syntax.  Touche good sir.  Touche.

Comment: `((helloCount += 1))` or `((helloCount++))`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(printf "\01")
b=hello
sed -e "s/\<$b\>/ $a /g" -e "s/[^$a]//g" -e "s/$a/ $b /g" file | wc -w
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat $FileName | tr '[\040]' '[\012]' | grep $word | wc -l
```

This Command will change space in new line then easily you can grep that word and count number of lines those are containing given word.

Answer (score 0):

Only change the "needle" and the "file"

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

needle="|"
file="file_example.txt"

IFS=$'\n'

counter=0
for line in `cat $file`
do
    counter=$[$counter+1]
    echo $counter"|"`echo $line | grep -o "$needle" | wc -l`
done
```

It will print the line number and the number of occurrences, separated by a pipe character